# Adding title for each part of layer control in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-layer-control

I create a Leaflet map containing some base maps and overlay maps. I want to organize the layer control so that these two parts separated by a title,
so I want to have such a view on my layer control:

Basemaps

- Satellite
- OSM

Personal Maps

- Cities
- Markets
- Parks

How can I do such design? My code as below does not work:

```
var Basemaps = {
    "OSM": OSM,
    'Google Satellite':googleSat,
};
var overlayMaps = {
    "Cities": Cities, 
    "Markets": Markets,
    "Parks": Parks
}

var layerControl=L.control.layers(Basemaps, overlayMaps, {
    collapsed: false,
    baseLayersLabel: 'Base Layers',
    overlayLayersLabel: 'Overlayed Maps'
}).addTo(map);
```

I add overlay maps from external JavaScript files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that. I should add the code below in head part:

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/ismyrnow/Leaflet.groupedlayercontrol/master/src/leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js"></script>
```

and then use that layers as follows:

```
// Overlay layers are grouped
var groupedOverlays = {
    SelectType: {
    Type1Layer: L1,
    Type2Layer: L2
    },
    SelectCategory: {
    Category1: L3,
    Category2: L4
    }
};

L.control.groupedLayers(Basemaps, groupedOverlays).addTo(map);
```